CDS View select from parameterized view
I have a CDS view with parameters defined like this:
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'CFIMSPLANACT2501'
@EndUserText.label: 'mspa'
@VDM.viewType: #CONSUMPTION
@Analytics.query: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #PRIVILEGED_ONLY
@Analytics.settings.maxProcessingEffort: #HIGH
@ClientHandling.algorithm: #SESSION_VARIABLE
@AbapCatalog.buffering.status: #NOT_ALLOWED
@Metadata.ignorePropagatedAnnotations: true

@ObjectModel.supportedCapabilities: [ #ANALYTICAL_QUERY ]
@ObjectModel.modelingPattern: #ANALYTICAL_QUERY
@ObjectModel.usageType.sizeCategory: #XXL
@ObjectModel.usageType.serviceQuality: #D
@ObjectModel.usageType.dataClass: #MIXED

define view C_MarketSegmentPlanActQ2501
with parameters

    @EndUserText.label: 'Plan Category'
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.variableSequence: 40
    P_PlanningCategory : fcom_category,

    @Semantics.businessDate.at: true
    @Environment.systemField: #SYSTEM_DATE
    P_KeyDate          : vdm_v_key_date,

    @Consumption.hidden: true
    @Environment.systemField: #SYSTEM_LANGUAGE
    P_Language         : sylangu,

    @Consumption.hidden: true
    @Environment.systemField: #USER
    P_BusinessUser     : syuname,

    @Consumption.hidden: true
    @Consumption.derivation: { lookupEntity: 'I_UserSetGetParamForCtrlgArea',
          resultElement: 'ControllingArea',
          binding: [ { targetElement : 'BusinessUser' , type : #PARAMETER, value : 'P_BusinessUser' } ] }
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.variableSequence: 5
    P_ControllingArea  : kokrs,

    @Consumption.derivation: { lookupEntity: 'I_Ledger',
      resultElement: 'Ledger',
      binding:
      [ { targetElement : 'IsLeadingLedger' ,
          type : #CONSTANT,
          value : 'X'
        }
      ]
    }
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.variableSequence: 10
    P_Ledger           : fins_ledger
  as select from`

I want to call this view from another view:
define view Z_Test as select from CFIMSPLANACT2501(
      P_PlanningCategory : 'PLN_CAT',   // Replace 'PLN_CAT' with the actual planning category you want to use
      P_KeyDate          : $session.system_date,  // Replace '20240101' with the actual key date
      P_Language         : $session.system_language,        // Replace 'EN' with the actual language
      P_BusinessUser     : '100',  // Replace 'BUS_USER' with the actual business user
      P_ControllingArea  : 'CONT_AREA', // Replace 'CONT_AREA' with the actual controlling area
      P_Ledger           : 'Leading Ledger'       // Replace 'LDGR' with the actual ledger
      )
{
    // Select the fields you need from the C_MarketSegmentPlanActQ2501 view
    CustomerGroup,
    MaterialGroup
}

But I get this error:

"CFIMSPLANACT2501" requires a parameter binding; use the associated CDS entity

But why do I have to bind when using hard coded values?
How can I solve this?
